# Objective C one class not seeing the other

Tags: objective-c

I have these two classes MobRec & MobDef and I want to reference an array pointer of (MobDef) *mobInfo from MobRec. #import the mobdefs.h file in MobRec.h or .m but no luck any ideas?

```
MobRec.h
// Basic class unit 
@interface MobRec : NSObject { 
NSString *mName; 
int speed; 
} 
@end 

MobDef.h
// Master Class holding an array of units 
@interface MobDef : NSObject { 
NSMutableArray *mobInfo; 
} 

@property(retain) NSMutableArray *mobInfo;  
@end 

MobDef.m
@synthesize MobInfo; 

- (id)init { // to add a new node and initialize it 
mobInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
MobRec *aNewMobRec = [[MobRec alloc] init]; 
[mobInfo addObject:aNewMobRec];  
[aNewMobRec release]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that individual files have no knowledge of other files in your project, since Objective-C is a derivative of C. You need to `#import` the header files of any other classes that you need to use:

```
// ModDef.m
#import "MobDef.h"
#import "ModRec.h"

@implementation MobDef

@synthesize mobInfo; // case matters here

- (id)init
{
    mobInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MobRec* aNewMobRec = [[MobRec alloc] init];
    [mobInfo addObject:aNewMobRec];
    [aNewMobRec release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `@synthesize` doesn't match `@property` declaration - you're declaring properties for `mobInfo` but generating synthesized accessors for `MobInfo`.

Of are you getting some other error?